# An exercise to the zero-dimensional homology

Tags: group-theory

We are working in Munkre's Algebraic Topology:

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $\phi:G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be an epimorphism. Show that $G$ has an infinite cyclic subgroup $H$ such that $G=(ker\phi)\oplus H$.

So the suggested hint is to define a homomorphism $\psi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ such that $(\phi \circ \psi)=id_{\mathbb{Z}}$. I figure we can do this by grabbing a random element of $\phi^{-1}(1)$ and using that to induce $\psi$. We do this to get that $Im (\psi)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, then apply first isomorphism theorem? So $G/(ker\phi)\cong \mathbb{Z}\cong H$, so $G\cong (ker\phi)\oplus H$.

Is this valid? I am getting back into study after a break from school and am trying to make sure I am getting a feel for technicalities I may be overlooking in proof techniques.  Also, I recall exact sequences back in the day, but didn't understand their full takeaway... Is this preparing us for techniques to produce/take advantage of such sequences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints on how you might argue, using your (correct) idea: since $\phi$ is onto, by the first isomophism theorem, $\mathbb Z\cong G/\ker \phi$. Fix  $g_1\in \{\phi^{-1}(1)\}$ and show that $\langle g_1\rangle$ is infinite. Then, if $g\in G,$ there is an integer $n$ such that $\phi(g)=n.$ Now, $g=ng_1+(g-ng_1)$, which means that $G=\langle g_1\rangle+\ker \phi$ and so it only remains to prove that $\langle g_1\rangle\cap\ker \phi=\{0\}.$

(Since you mentioned exact sequences, the easy way to do this is to observe that the short exact sequence $\ 0\longrightarrow \ker \phi\overset{i}\longrightarrow G\overset{\phi}\longrightarrow \mathbb Z\ $ is split, so $G\cong \ker\phi\oplus\mathbb Z$).